# Found my Multibit.key wallet back up, but I do not remember the password, what next?

Tags: multibit, wallet-recovery

I created a Multibit wallet back up many years ago and it was saved as multibit.key. 
I am now trying to import this back into MultiBit Classic and it is asking for a password. I have forgotten the password.

Is there anything I can try? Is brute forcing an option? What type of software would I have to use?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [btcrecover](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover) to attempt to brute force your password. However, if you have no idea what the password could be, then it isn't going to be able to help much.